# Deploy a war file on a different version of MobileFirst Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, mobilefirst-server

I deployed a war file in a WAS server and when I opened the MobileFirst console it says:

"No runtime environment deployed in this server."

When I checked the logs it says that the mobileFirst version which I generated the war file is 7.1.0 and my server in which I'm going to deploy it is v7.0.0. I want to deploy my war file on our server which is v7.0.0 since that's the one that has a license.

I'm thinking to generate a war file with v7.0.0 on my current environment which is v7.1.0 but I can't figure out how. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a 7.0.0 .war file when developing using 7.1.0.

7.1 generates 7.1
7.0 generates 7.0

You can deploy 7.0 .war file in 7.1 server
Not the opposite.

Comment: The MobileFirst Studio available in eclipse market place is the latest. Do you know where can I get the older version 7.0.0? Our company also bought a license of v7.0.0 do they have a cd or installer for that?

Comment: You can download previous releases by downloading the latest iFix of the needed release from the IBM Fix Central website.